# Как сделать такую функцию?

Tags: javascript

Есть тег span со значением 15, как через некие интервалы времени уменьшать это значение, то есть 15, 14, 13, 12, 11.... Использовать метод setInterval, но как уменьшать значение?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  var span = document.querySelector("span")

  if (!--span.textContent) {
    clearInterval(interval)
  }
}, 1000)
```

```html
<span>15</span>
```

Comment: А как сделать проверку, если значение span == 1 то выполнить метод clearInterval?

Comment: объясните, как работает if (!--span.textContent) ?

Comment: @NeedHate, берётся текст из span.textContent, оператором декремента приводится к числу, число уменьшается на 1, записывается обратно в span.textContent (преобразуясь в строку), а также к нему (уменьшенному числу) применяется отрицание, из-за чего 0 превращается в true. Если что (в спане не число), NaN тоже превратится в true, но в спане отобразится NaN.

Comment: @Евгений, поменяй отрицание на сравнение с 1.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77539/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy----).

Answer (score 2):

```
var span = document.querySelector(".bonus");
span.innerText = (+span.innerText) - 1;
```

Comment: А вот у тега span есть класс bonus, "span.innerText = (+span.innerText) - 1;"  как это класс в коде записать?) я в Js чайник))

Comment: Зачем использовать явное приведение к числу, когда там и так вычитание?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я с интересом наблюдаю, как ты это объясняешь под своим ответом ).

Comment: @Igor, у меня вообще декремент. А тут - просто минус. Но минус тоже сам приводит к числу. Странно, что тут никто не спросил, зачем тут плюс. Да, ещё, `innerText` - это медленное сомнительное свойство, которое в стандарт добавили (кажется добавили) примерно с год назад и которым в 99% случаев пользоваться вообще не надо. От него даже в jQuery отказались.

Answer (score 0):

Всё становится лучше с jQuery ;)

```js
$.fn.countdown = function(start, period = 1000) {
  this.text(start);
  var t = setInterval(() => this.text() == 1 ? clearInterval(t) : this.text(this.text()-1), period);
};

$('.bonus').countdown(15);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class=bonus>Счётчик</span>
```

---

Почти то же самое на vanillaJs:

```js
function Countdown(selector) {
  var el = document.querySelector(selector), t;
  this.start = start;

  function start(from, interval = 1000, to = 1) {
    el.textContent = from; // Инициализация
    if (t) clearInterval(t); // На случай повторного запуска
    t = setInterval(tick.bind(null, to), interval);
  }
  
  function tick(to) {
    if (!t) return;
    if (el.textContent == to) {
      clearInterval(t); // Остановка таймера
      t = null;
    } else {
      el.textContent--; // Собственно, уменьшение
    }      
  };
}

new Countdown('.bonus').start(15, 500);
```

```html
<span class=bonus>Счётчик</span>
```

Comment: jQuery не просили.

Comment: Ну, без него вы уже всё расхватали. Вдруг пригодится)

Comment: А ещё плохо много раз оборачивать один и тот же this.

Comment: Преждевременная оптимизация же. Ок, он же вроде там уже jQ-контейнер?

Comment: Вроде это считается общепринятой, а не преждевременной. А вообще да - он там уже обёрнут, потому что это плагин, а не обработчик события.